# Copy docker configuration to other PC

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I’m using docker composer in order to run ChirpStack on my Windows 10 machine. I need to reinstall operating system, but how to keep working ChirpStack docker system without creating new one?

Comment: you need to create a image from the container when you want to persist the current files

Answer (score 0):

If all the base images you're using are from public repos and are not only saved on your machine you only need to save your docker configuration, since you're using docker compose you can just copy the docker-compose.yml file to an external storage medium and you're all set. Unless you have some more dependencies that only exist on your computer that's all the files you need.